# Fetch database from production to development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I love very much heroku database pulling:

```
heroku db:pull
```

It is very helpful when you are fixing bugs caused by data at production.

Is it any gems that can easily pull database from production without heroku?

Comment: Please note that you can also use `heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL your_local_db_name`. Works a lot faster than heroku's taps implementation. More info here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/issues/42

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Tap gem: https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps. This should do what you want.

Comment: taps is great gem, but very buggy